# KMail: Search for messages with attachment

Tags: kde, search, kmail

How can I search for messages with one or more attachments in KMail?

The search filters don't show such an option, and when selecting "Message Status" there also isn't a criteria for attachments.

[image: KMail search dialog]

I'm using KMail 4.13.3.

Comment: what kmail version are you using? In kmail from KDE 4.13 there is a "has attachment" search filter

Comment: I'm using KMail 4.13.3, but there's no "has attachment" filter.

Comment: I mean in the quick filter bar, on the top right of the UI, you should use that to search emails with attachments.

Comment: You're right, there's a filter for attachments. But this search box only works for the current directory, I want to find mails with attachments in all folders.

Comment: then you should search via the search windows in all folders, then open the search result and apply the "has attachment" filter there

Comment: Well, that would be a useful workaround. However, if I use this filter, all mails disappear, although there are mails with attachments (which I confirmed). Somehow, KMail doesn't recognize if the mails have attachments in the search results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16131/discussion-between-bob-and-dcmst).